# How to trim the attributes value in solr direclty

Tags: search, solr, solr6

Can we use TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory to trim the values of a particular /all the attributes directly in solr from document screen, without resyncing the full data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, update processors are applied when an update is performed (.. as is in the name). Since the indexing operation might not be a lossless process, filters can't be applied after the document has been indexed.

Reindex the document and apply the update chain with the filter active.